# Rsyslog with custom TLS connection

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

I have configured Rsyslog to transmit through Tls everything works good but I want to force the Rsyslog client to send through Tls version 1.1 or above and customize the encryption algorithm that uses for Tls.

client config file

```
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog


$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog


global(
defaultNetstreamDriverCAFile = "/etc/ssl/certs/rsyslog_ca.pem" 
)

if $msg contains', "operation": '  or $msg contains "[f:" or $msg 
contains "sshd" or $msg contains "[NET] " or $msg contains "[MGR] " or 
$msg contains "[IKE] " or $msg contains "[JOB] " or $msg contains " 
[ENC] " or $msg contains "[CFG] " or $msg contains "[LIB] " or $msg 
contains "[KNL] "  then action(type="omfwd" target = "192.168.5.228" 
port = "514" protocol = "tcp"  TCP_Framing="octet-counted" 
StreamDriver="gtls" StreamDriverMode="1" 
StreamDriverAuthMode="x509/certvalid" rebindinterval = "10000"  
queue.filename = "192-168-5-228-tcp-514" queue.type = 
"fixedarray" queue.size = "100")
```

I don't want Rsyslog to use these algorithm secp244r1, secp192r1

Comment: You are lacking many relevant details in order to get help. This will be a good starting point: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this and working for me

```
  'gnutlsPriorityString="SECURE128:-VERS-TLS1.0:-CAMELLIA-128-CBC:-ECDHE-RSA:- 
   AES-256-GCM:-AEAD"
```